# How to access a singleton Android Activity in a backstack multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent

A1 is the main activity. It is a single instance activity meaning it should not be instantiated more than once since it is expensive to re-create it.

The scenario is:

- A1 calls A2
- A2 calls A3
- A3 calls A1

Expected backstack is:

Top -> **[A1|A3|A2|A1]** <- bottom

I would like A1 stay on the top of this stack. Therefore, when I hit the back button, I expect to return to A3, then A2, and finally back to A1.

Currently A1 is defined as launchMode=*singleinstance*. Naturally, second call to A1 clears all other activities (A2 and A3) from the backstack.

**Question is, how can I let a singleton activity exist in a backstack more than once for navigation purposes?**

Note: Assuming that the backstack structure is internally composed of **references** to the activities, then somehow I should be able to create two different references to a singleton Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I let a singleton activity exist in a backstack more than once for navigation purposes?

You can't. You would have to override default BACK button behavior, probably on all your activities, so that you force the flow to be what you want and do not `finish()` A1 until you are sure that you are done with it.

Or, rework your navigation to avoid A3 launching A1. For example, use a nav drawer to allow the user to get back to A1 whenever the user wants, but where you can wipe out the back stack as part of that navigation.

Or, make A1 cheaper, so creating two instances are not so expensive. Rarely are activities themselves expensive; usually, it is something that the activity loads that is expensive, and that could be shared (carefully) via singleton caches.

Or, consolidate this all into one activity, with fragments F1 through F3, where you will have a somewhat easier time hand-rolling the navigation.

> Assuming that the backstack structure is internally composed of references to the activities, then somehow I should be able to create two different references to a singleton Activity.

No. That is akin to saying "assuming that the Web browser's back stack structure is internally composed of references to Web pages, then somehow I should be able to create two different references to a singleton Web page". Last I checked, that is not possible in Web development, because there is no such thing as a "singleton Web page". Android does not really have the concept of a "singleton activity", either -- `singleInstance` is really there more for navigation from outside the app into the app.